# Converting local user password to secure string does not work

Tags: powershell

I am needing to change local user passwords. When I convert it to a secure string, it acts as if it changed it, but when trying to login to the account it does not take the password. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I know for Powershell's Set-LocalUser cmdlet to take a password it must be a secure string. Below is the code

```
$UnsecurePassword = "Testing1234"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $UnsecurePassword -AsPlainText -Force
$localaccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "Local" -ea stop | Enable-LocalUser
$localaccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $SecurePassword -PasswordNeverExpires 1 -ea stop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the line

```
$localaccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "Local" -ea stop | Enable-LocalUser
```

As [Enable-LocalUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.LocalAccounts/Enable-LocalUser?view=powershell-5.1) doesn't return anything and also hasn't a `-PassThru` parameter, you end up with `$localaccount` being empty.

So change your script to:

```
$UnsecurePassword = "Testing1234"
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $UnsecurePassword -AsPlainText -Force
$localaccount = Get-LocalUser -Name "Local" -ea stop 
$localaccount | Enable-LocalUser
$localaccount | Set-LocalUser -Password $SecurePassword -PasswordNeverExpires 1 -ea stop
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying it out now.

Comment: You saved me so much time. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest way to set the password, you can add in your other stuff to make sure its enabled and whatever else you want. In terms of setting a password this is the easiest way to do it in my opinion.

```
Set-LocalUser -Name Local -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Testing1234' -AsPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: This way worked too, but I prefer my structure to be similar to LotPings script posted.

Comment: The command in a admin powershell session did not return any feedback. But the password was changed! Even a one char password works. Can I set no password, i.e. an empty string? I get `ConvertTo-SecureString: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is an empty string.`

Answer (score 0):

#### Minimal solution in powershell > 5, Win 10

##### TL;DR:

```
Set-LocalUser -Name Local -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString 1234 -AsPlainText)
```

#### Findings

You can omit the `force` parameter for a minimal solution in opposition to the other's answer.

A naive approach would be `Set-LocalUser local` to change the password to **no password**. Try it, in `powershell` it does not work. Unsetting a password works in the `gui` in windows 10 though.